# Python Programming Error for DataScience DataFrame

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, machine-learning

I am reading my data from a CSV file using pandas and it works well with range 700. But as soon as I go above 700 and trying to append to a list in python it is showing me list index out of range. But the CSV has around 500K of rows
Can anyone help me with that why is it happening? 
Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd

df_email = pd.read_csv('emails.csv',nrows=800)
test_email = df_email.iloc[:,-1]


list_of_emails = []

for i in range(len(test_email)):    
    var_email = test_email[i].split("\n") #this code takes one single email splits based on a new line giving a python list of all the strings in the email


    email = {}
    message_body = ''

    for _ in var_email:
        if ":" in _:
            var_sentence = _.split(":") #this part actually uses the ":" to find the elements in the list that have ":" present

            for j in range(len(var_sentence)):           
                if var_sentence[j].lower().strip() == "from":
                    email['from'] = var_sentence[var_sentence.index(var_sentence[j+1])].lower().strip()
                elif  var_sentence[j].lower().strip() == "to":  
                    email['to'] = var_sentence[var_sentence.index(var_sentence[j+1])].lower().strip()
                elif var_sentence[j].lower().strip() == 'subject':
                    if var_sentence[var_sentence.index(var_sentence[j+1])].lower().strip() == 're':
                        email['subject'] = var_sentence[var_sentence.index(var_sentence[j+2])].lower().strip()
                    else:
                        email['subject'] = var_sentence[var_sentence.index(var_sentence[j+1])].lower().strip()

        elif ":" not in _:
            message_body += _.strip()
            email['body'] = message_body

    list_of_emails.append(email)
```

Comment: If you show us the code we maybe able to help you

Comment: It would be easy to answer, if you share the code you are getting error in and also the file, if possible.

Comment: "trying to append to a list in python": don't do that if you have Pandas available. Pandas has a `read_csv` function which you should use.

Comment: Please use a code-block to fully format the relevant code; much easier to read.

Comment: yeah I am doing read_csv method from panda and using nrows argument to mention how many i want to extract from the csv. There if I use nrows=700 and then when I am trying to create a new dataframe from a list where I appended the rows by data manipulation it works fine but as soon as I make the nrows=800 or even 701 it doesn't work and appending to the list says list index out of range

Comment: I am sorry for the code format since this is my first question in stack overflow and don't have a lot of idea how to post code

Comment: And sorry Sam cannot upload the file since its 480MB else if you can give an email address I can upload the file in google drive and share that and anyone else if it is easier to debug the code of find the error with the csv file I am using

Comment: There's a help icon when you enter or edit a question; that can provide you with information about formatting a question (or go directly to https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: I will keep that in mind evert.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to make a lot of sense: you're selecting the last column from the data frame, then split on a newline for each entry in that column. Aren't newlines used as record separator in the original CSV file? How are there newlines in the single entries?

Comment: the format of the data is in each line
The data is basically an email where you have a message id, date, from,to each in the new line so using split with "\n" will make each data an element in a python list removing the new lines.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what you are trying to say here (might as well put example inputs and outputs here), but I came across this problem, which might be of the same nature, sometime weeks ago.

CSV files are comma-separated, which means it always takes note of every comma in a line to separate them in columns. If some dirty input from strings in your CSV file are present, then it will mess up the columns that you are expecting to have.

Best solution here is have some code to cleanup your CSV file, change its delimiter to another character (probably '|', '&', or anything that also doesn't mess up with the data), and revise your code to reflect these changes to the CSV.

Comment: As an addition, you can set the delimiter in pandas.read_csv() with `sep` or `delimiter` set to the delimiter of your choice, e.g. `sep='|'`. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html for more details on its use.

Answer (score 0):

use the pandas library to read the file.

it is very efficient and saves you time in writing the code yourself.

eg :

```
import pandas as pd
training_data = pd.read_csv( "train.csv", sep = ",", header = None )
```